# Migrating database ms access 2003 to 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm very new to Access and I don't have any experience. At work, I was ask to research about migration of MS Access 2003 databases to 2007.

I have read on the Internet that usually if you open `.mdb` files in Access 2007 it will normally work. But in my case I'm getting an error:

> Action Failed

Now I'm not sure if I'm getting the correct file here.

Here is the structure of the file of the database. The database name is: Energy.

```
Folder Energy:
Access2003
Energy.app
System.MDW
Energy (it's a link)
Energy.ini
```

I made a copy of my `Energy.app` and then renamed it to `Energy.mdb`. And this file `Energy.mdb` I opened in Access 2007. Then I got the error. How can I find the `.mdb` file? Did I do the right thing?

I also read that I have to make a copy of the front-end or back end of my database. I'm not sure where is the front end and back end now.

Is it in the SQL Server? Thanks for your help in advance.

---

### Additional Question

I tried to follow this one from the website:

#### Method 2: Move the database to a trusted location

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Determine trusted locations to which you can move the database. To do this, follow these steps:
2. Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Access Options.
   Click Trust Center, and then click Trust Center Settings under Microsoft Office Access Trust Center.
3. Click Trusted Locations, and then use one of the following procedures:
   Note the paths of the trusted locations that are listed.
   Add a new trusted location. To do this, click Add new location, and then specify the path of the location that you want to add.
4. Move the Access 2007 database to the trusted location that you want.

But it seems it didn't work. The error I'm getting is after I deactivate the macro under option is this:

> Error in Connection
>   SQLState '28000'
>   SQLServer Error 18452
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQl Server] Login Failed for user '(null)' Reason: not associated with a trusted SQL server connection

But I already added a new folder to the trusted location, as mentioned on the KB

Comment: Are you certain the original file, "Access2003 Energy.app" is not named "Access2003 Energy.adp"? If so, don't rename it to MDB, just open it directly -- ADP is the alternate front end format for connecting to SQL Server databases. It's no longer actively promoted by the Access team, though, so you don't want to invest too much energy in it -- it's a dead-end technology.

Comment: hi David,that's the one I can see in the folder of this database. The folder name is Energy and in it are these: 1) Access2003(this is another folder) and in it are Energy.app and System.MDW. 2) Energy (a link) and 3) Energy.ini

Comment: i'm not sure how to identify the front-end format and back-end. Could you please show me how to differentiate it? Do you mean I'll just open the Energy.app directly in ms access 2007? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931407/)

Are you allowingtrusted mode?

Comment: hi astander, thanks for the link. Do I have to do this in ms access 2007? Or in SQL Server?

Comment: the link says that you need to do this in ms access 2007. Are you moving from access to sql server?

Comment: First I would like to open the .mdb files to access 2007 see if it works. If it works then we have to migrate from 2003 to 2007.

Comment: At the top, below the ribbon, it give you a warning
"Security Worning - Certain content in the database has been disabled - Options..." do you see this?

Comment: yes I see this. Actually I tried to open this several times and also activate but still I'm getting an error message.

Comment: Do you have any macros that you run on open, any code that you run that might be failing?

Comment: the old database has macros active. i tried to activate the macros in ms access 2007 it seems still to fail.

Comment: i think the next step would be to check what those macros are doing, or trying to debug that. can you show me what you are trying to do in those macros?

Comment: you mean in ms access 2003 macro? or in ms access 2007? in ms access 2007, i clicked on the option and activate the macro from here.and every time i opened it i have to activate it.

Comment: the file that you are trying to convert, (i assume it is originally from access 2003). Does it have any macros or code running on startup? I think if so, this might be the code that is causing the error.

Comment: yes that's right. it's originally from access 2003 and it has macros running on start up. this file from access 2003, i'm trying to open it to ms access 2007. because the goal is to convert the ms access 2003 to ms access 2007.

Comment: Yes, i understood that. So now my guess would be that what ever is running in that macro is what is failing. If you can give me a clue as to what you are trying to do in the macro, amybe i can then investigate that.

Comment: ok. you mean in the macro ms access 2003? I'm not really sure what to look in macro. could you give me a hint what to look? thanks. this project is done by somebody and i have to spell all the works done here.i'm thankful for your ideas and help

Comment: Typically the macro calls a function in VBA code. This will then execute steps, such as set settings, hide forms, update values etc.

In access 2003. Under the Macros tab (should be below reports,pages), do you have any macros there, and if so, what are they called?

Comment: i opened the access 2003 - i make a copy of the Enery.app and renamed it to Energy.mdb & then hold the shift tab and open. under the macro & i'm seeing the Autoexec and mcrTool.

Comment: OK, thats good. The Autoexec is the one that runs when you open the db normally (without shift). Now the next question, what is the autoexec doing, is it calling a vba function in one of the modules?

Comment: hmm how will i know that? what function shall i look? do i have to open the VBA code?

Comment: Under the Macros, select Autoexec, right click and open in design view. Tell me what you see inside the macro, what is it doin?

Comment: it opens like an excel file with a name at the top: Autoexec: Macro and under Action: ExecuteCode und under the Functions Name : InitApplication(). that's all

Comment: OK, thats good. Now, in the VBA code, in a Module you will find this InitApplication() function. Look for that edit your question to copy that code in if you are allowed to, and leave a comment again for me to find so that i can have a look at that code. I think your issue is in that code...

Comment: i just opened any Module and already copied the code. You can see it now in my edited question. I have a little background on C# but not on VB

Comment: Sorry, was out for the day, will have alook at it as soon as possible. Adriaan

Comment: MK, the code came out a bit funny in the post. Tell me, do you know how to debug the code? When you open it in access 2007 (using shift, to avoid it running the marco), you need to go the the vba code where the function InitApplication is. On the line that says "Application.Echo 1, conStart" press F9, this should insert a break point. Now you can go back to the macros section, double click and debug the code. See if you can find the line where the code fails. Other than that, goto (in vba code) DEBUG->Compile. Does it give errors?

Comment: hello Adriann, thanks for the reply and sorry also for the late reply.I'm new to programming and I don't know how to debug but I'll really try. Today I'm getting another problem with my ms access 2007. If I double clicked on that, I'm getting this one: 
http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vvrpn8&s=4
this is really strange....

Comment: Im sorry, my german is a bit bad X-), can you translate what the messages are saying?

Comment: no problem:) That means: "Please wait while Microsoft Office professional Plus 2007 is being configured by Windows. Required information are being collected" Sorry about that, the German translation is really very bad. At the moment, I can't think how to translate it well in English. 
The Blue Window it just says: "Status Configuration" "Microsoft Office Professional is being configured"...

Comment: hi astander, you mentioned in your prev comment, that I should find the line "Application.Echo 1" I already found it and already inserted the breakpoint. And you said I go back to the macros section again. In my macros section I have Autoexec and mcrTool,which one should I click?

Comment: This is really strange. I tried to put the break point where the "Application.Echo 1, conStart" and double click the AutoExec macro, nothing happened. I go back to Debug >Compile it's grayed out- hmmm, do you have any idea?

Comment: i am getting a bit stumped. if at all possible, is there somewhere you can post the db file, so i can have a look at it local?

Comment: that should be fine adriaanstander@webmail.co.za This is a free site, so the file cannot be to big, sorry...

Comment: Yes, i did get it, but at home i only have 2003, which helps us nothing X-). At work i have 2007, so i can check there.

Comment: i see ok, thanks again for your time. let me know what results you get:)

Comment: hi Adriann, were you able to check the db I sent?